# how can i make 3 java class for size, font, color to change my whole app text?

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an app that have a menu .
my menu items are font,color,size ,
and i have 3 class but my problem is that i cant to apply these classes to my activity.
is this ok? it isn't logically true
and this is my class for font:

```
public class font extends Activity implements
        RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    public static String font = "aldhabi.ttf";
    RadioGroup f;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.font);

        f = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiofont);
        f.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int CheckedId) {

        switch (CheckedId) {

        case R.id.font1:
            font = "aldhabi.ttf";
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.font2:
            font = "ALGER.TTF";
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.font3:
            font = "andlso.ttf";
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.font4:
            font = "MAGNETOB.TTF";
            finish();
            break;

        }

    }

    protected String getFont() {
        return font;
    }
}
```

and this my method in my main activity:

```
@override
public void setFonts() {

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/"
            + fonts + "");
    textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    String str = textView.getText().toString();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    font a = new font();
    fonts = a.getFont();
    setFace();
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is not a class but just a method.
The code in your comment is unreadable. You can edit your original post and add the code there. Please do that.

Comment: I Want to create 3 method that use them in my manin activity.